# Instantiate Child Object with Parent config or 'downcast parent to child'

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting

I am not sure what the best practice for downcasting from parent to child  or creating a `B` (`extends A`) out of `A` is.

As an example I have two classes:

**The parent one:**

```
public class SoccerPlayer  {

    private String name;
    private SoccerShoe shoe;
    private SoccerJersey jersey;
    /* ... */
}
```

**And the child one:**

```
public class Goalkeeper extends SoccerPlayer {

    private GoalkeeperGlove glove;
    /* ... */
}
```

---

Now a regular soccer player wants to be a Goalkeeper. What can I do? Obviously the following would not work:

```
    SoccerPlayerArrayOfTeamA[0] = new SoccerPlayer("Robert");

    /*... new career path ...*/

    SoccerPlayerArray[0] = (Goalkeeper) SoccerPlayerArray[0]
```

But that is what I would say "I want to do"...
The new Instance of the child class (`Goalkeeper`) should have all variable configurations as the old Instance of the parent class (`SoccerPlayer`). (e.g. `name`, `jersey` ...)
Is there an OOP way to do that I do I have to set every variable manually as in the following?

```
    /*... new career path ...*/

   SoccerPlayer temp = SoccerPlayerArray[0]
   SoccerPlayerArray[0] = new Goalkeeper(temp.getName());
   SoccerPlayerArray[0].setJersey(temp.getJersey());
```

Comment: Your OO design is wrong if you need to change the type of the object dynamically. An object is an instance of the same class, always. Its type can't change. It's either a goalkeeper or a field player from the beginning.

Comment: @Magnamag Thats a good point! Its part of a complex system, but I'll try to change the creation process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Decorator Design Pattern. E.g. Java IO classes.

When any object dynamically wants to change its behavior then you can wrap that object with the desired object. Like if `C wants to become B` then B should have a constructor which accepts C and then the methods in B should use C where ever appropriate. Best example is when `FileInputStream wants to become BufferedInputStream` you can just create `BufferedInputStream` by passing `FileInputStream` in its constructor but it does not need to copy properties of `FileInputStream`.

Comment: How would that help me? Could you please elaborate? When `B implements A` (Goolkeeper implements Player) and `C implements A` (Soccerplayer implements Player), I can't cast C to B (Soccerplayer to Goalkeeper)...

Comment: When any object dynamically wants to change its behavior then you can wrap that object with the desired object. Like if `C wants to become B` then B should have a constructor which accepts C and then the methods in B should use C where ever appropriate. Best example is when `FileInputStream wants to become BufferedInputStream` you can just create `BufferedInputStream by passing FileInputStream` in its constructor but it does not need to copy properties of `FileInputStream`.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a bit more detail - including some of the comment detail in it for clarity perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Add a copy constructor to Goalkeeper that accepts SoccerPlayer as an argument.

Comment: But then I have to set every variable manually in the copy constructor, right?

Comment: Yes. There's no real way around that. But this is in one place.